# Is there a way to use a for loop, in typescript, to generate a div tag?

Tags: angular, typescript, loops

I am working on creating a calendar with Angular and Typescript. I was following a tutorial that uses JavaScript. For the life of me I cannot figure out how to make it work in Typescript.

I am trying to use a loop to create a div for each iteration.

JavaScript code is as follows:

```
let days= "";

for(let i= 1; i <= lastDay; i++){
  days += `<div>${i}</div>`;
  monthDays.innerHTML = days;
}
```

lastDay is a number
monthDays refers to the div element that the new divs will live in.

I have tried to use a function that includes the loop this resulted in the wrong type being returned.

generateDays = (lastDay:number) => {
for(let i=1; i<=lastDay; i++) {
this.days += `<div>${i}</div>`;
}}

In the case of using this function..
monthDays: string = this.generateDays(this.lastDay);

Comment: What was the wrong type? Can you include the function that you created in your question?

Comment: If you have access to Angular's machinery, why would you want to use a `for` loop to do this?

Comment: I must admit I'm quite new to all of this so I'm really not sure how Angular can help me.  The function I created I will post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, create an array of days in your component TS

```
this.days = Array(lastDay).fill(1).map((x, y) => x + y);
```

Then in your template do this:

```
<div *ngFor=let n of days">day {{ n }}</div>
```

Comment: I had been trying not to use ngFor but it does work. No particular reason in not using just challenging myself. Thank you for the help!